# Jboss7.2 and Java8

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jboss, cxf

I am going to deployee war file in Jboss 7.2 which is upgraded from java7 to java8.But I am getting bellow error at the time of deploying. Please help me to resolve it

```
ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "webservice-host.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"webservice-host.war\".undertow-deployment" => "org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'cxf' available
```

Comment: do you use soap webService in your application ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these configuration to your Spring Context XML file

```
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-xml.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml"/>
```

If it did not resolve your issue please paste the complete stack trace here